# Wordpress "Connection Lost. Saving has been disabled until you're reconnected." Error only when posting to Home Page

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I have a WordPress 5.9.2 website and I'm using Elementor 3.6.5. I start to get **"Connection Lost. Saving has been disabled until you're reconnected."** error when I try to make any changes to my Home Page ***only*** after a while. I tried to clear my cache and cookies but i didn't work. I also tried other browsers and different internet connections but the issue still remains. I also tried other computers but in some of them I get the same error and in some I don't. How can I solve the problem?
I have attached the error screenshot here.

[image]

Comment: What JS errors do you get? Can you check the JS Console in the developer tools? Can you also check the network tab in the developer tools, when you do the update click?

Answer (score 0):

Here is multiple factors that can cause this problem :

1. **The plugin/theme you installed** :
   Try to disable them *one to one* and see if the error remains.
2. **Resource limits from their server** : If you make *to many edits* for long enough, you may have the same error you have, this [API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/heartbeat-control/) solve the problem in this case.
3. **Issue from your hosting provider** : You can still go to their forum and see if it's their fault that you have this issue.

Hope it helps.